# Did `dnu restore` replaced `dotnet restore` on yeoman generator-aspnet?

Tags: asp.net-core, yeoman

I have ASP.NET Core (v1.0.0-preview2-003131) installed on my macOS Sierra, and installed yeoman generator-aspnet today(11/26/16). From my cli, I ran  `yo aspnet` and created my WebApplication but the options shown to use were `dnu restore`, `dnu build`, `dnx . kestrel`.

What happened to `dotnet restore` option? I even tried to run dotnet restore but it kept on looking for dnu.

[image: command line]

Answer (score 1):

No, DNU is part of the old DNX which was used up until rc1. RC2 and newer are based on dotnet-cli and the dotnet commands.

DNX isn't maintained anymore and shouldn't be use anymore. Just use the dotnet commands, ignoring what that generator says and report the issue [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet/issues).